# Vue js : render dynamic information in template with component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the *egoist/vue-html* plugin to render HTML, and it works fine with standard HTML, but fails when including a component tag.

For example, when including the `Breadcrumb` component in the template, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I've got so far:

```html
<script>
import Breadcrumb from '~components/Breadcrumb'
import Vue from 'vue'
import HTML from 'vue-html'

Vue.use(HTML)

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      html: '<div><Breadcrumb/></div>'
    }
  },
  render (h) {
    return this.$html(this.html)
  },
  components: {
    Breadcrumb
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what errors are you encountering (in the browser console, or in your bundler, e.g. webpack)?

Comment: Not found any error but not render component in browser.

Comment: **Breadcrumb** is a component not a tag.

Comment: could it be that you're not [registering your component](http://optimizely.github.io/vuejs.org/guide/composition.html#Registering_a_Component) at all?

Comment: *"Breadcrumb is a component not a tag."* - true, but in the context of HTML, it has a tag with the same name.

Comment: Yes in browser render with `<div><Breadcrumb/></div>` but breadcrumb component not replace with component html.

Comment: Try `<div><breadcrumb></breadcrumb></div>`

Comment: It's not working. @GOB

Answer (score 1):

Use a component name with a hyphen. Per [the draft spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-custom-elements-20160226/#h-concepts):

> The ***custom element type*** identifies a custom element interface and is a
>   sequence of characters that **must** match the NCName production
>   [XML-NAMES], **must** contain a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character, and **must
>   not** contain any uppercase ASCII letters [HTML]. The custom element
>   type **must not** be one of the following values:
>
> - annotation-xml
> - color-profile
> - font-face
> - font-face-src
> - font-face-uri
> - font-face-format
> - font-face-name
> - missing-glyph